# C# How can I populate a combo box using a SQL View with Multiple Columns

Tags: c#

I have a SQL View that I want to use to populate a comboBox.  This is the code I use to create a Var with the data.

```
var results = context.VW_HomicideDataSearch.Where(c => c.Case_Number.StartsWith(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Address.Contains(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Victim_Name.StartsWith(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Address.StartsWith(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Suspect.StartsWith(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Notes.Contains(e.Text)
                                                                  || c.Notes.Contains(e.Text));
```

And the results I get look like this:
[image]

I now need to get this into a format I can use to wire up a combo box. So I would need DataVaule field and a DataText field. I cannot seem to figure it out.  Is this evan possible and if so can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Well, what in that data do you want the "value" of the combobox items to be (an identifier of some sort) and what in that data do you want the displayed "text" of the combobox items to be?  That is, what should your combobox look like?

Comment: What values do you want as the data value and data text?

Comment: This is what the goal is.  I have a combo box I want to use to get a search term.  As the user types in the search term I evaluate the text with the code that gives me the Results.  The image I show was the results of typing in the word "fists".  The user would see what is displayed in the notes column. That data in mosts cases would be more descriptive.  If they select that value in the combo box and press a button I would then use the CaseId field as my filter to show the correct data in a datagrid.